# Is there a version of string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace for integers?

Tags: c#, isnullorempty

I'm fairly new to C# and programming in general and I've spent hours on trying to fix my basic program . I have 4 variables , I asked the user to input 3 of them and leave one empty . The program does calculations on the empty one but the problem is that I can't use the IsNullOrWhiteSpace for ints .

```
Console.WriteLine("ilk aracın hızını giriniz");
int v1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("ikinci aracın hızını giriniz");
int v2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("yolun uzunluğunu giriniz");
int  x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("karşılaşma sürelerini giriniz");
int t = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v1))
{
  v1 = x / t - v2;
  Console.WriteLine(v1);
}
else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v2))
{
  v2 = x / t - v1;
  Console.WriteLine(v2);
}
else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t))
{
  t = x / (v1 + v2);
  Console.WriteLine(t);
}
else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
{
  x = (v1 + v2) * t;
  Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

`
Is there a way to fix this ? If so how ?

Comment: nullable int `int?`

Comment: Try double n;
            bool isNumeric = Int.TryParse("5", out n);

Comment: Why not do `IsNullOrWhitespace()` on the source strings rather than immediately (and without any validation) convert them to `int`?

Answer (score 5):

There is no equivalent of `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` for `int`s because `int` always represents a number.

> I asked the user to input 3 of them and leave one empty.

One approach is to keep user input as `string`s up until the moment when you are ready to use its integer form:

```
Console.WriteLine("ilk aracın hızını giriniz");
string sv1 = Console.ReadLine();
```

Use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` on `sv1`, `sv2`, `sx`, `st`, and then convert inside the `if` statement:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s1)) {
    v1 = Convert.ToInt32(sx) / Convert.ToInt32(st) - Convert.ToInt32(sv2);
    Console.WriteLine(v1);
}
```

Note that this is integer division, so any fractional result of dividing `x` by `t` is truncated.

Another approach is to use `TryParse` on all four values, and avoid `IsNullOrWhitespace` altogether:

```
Console.WriteLine("ilk aracın hızını giriniz");
bool missingV1 = !int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var v1);
Console.WriteLine("ikinci aracın hızını giriniz");
bool missingV2 = !int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var v2);
Console.WriteLine("yolun uzunluğunu giriniz");
bool missingX = !int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var x);
Console.WriteLine("karşılaşma sürelerini giriniz");
bool missingT = !int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var t);
if (missingV1) {
    v1 = x / t - v2;
    Console.WriteLine(v1);
} else if (missingV2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: ... and int is not aware of any whitespace as a string :o)